# DOMPDF not working, giving error

Tags: php, dompdf

I have form.php file that getting data from mysql table.
**form.php**

```
<?php
 if(mysql_num_rows($sql)==0){
?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1.</td>
        <td>America</td>
    <tr>
</table>
<a href="pdf.php" target="_blank">Export as PDF</a>
<?php
 } else {
?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1.</td>
        <td>India</td>
    <tr>
</table>
<a href="pdf.php" target="_blank">Export as PDF</a>
<?php
 }
?>
```

And **pdf.php**

```
require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
ob_start();
$html = file_get_contents('form.php');
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$tym = date('g:i s');
$filename = 'FAA-8130_3_'.$tym;
$dompdf->load_html($html);
ob_end_flush();
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream($filename. ".pdf", array("Attachment" => 0));
```

When I try to export it as PDF file, it is giving error...

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepend_child() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\path\to\dompdf\include\frame_tree.cls.php on line 231

I could not understand why it is happening. I viewed [this](https://github.com/thujohn/pdf-l4/issues/55),[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16085009/dompdf-using-curl-instead-of-allow-url-fopen) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519011/php-fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-on-a-non-object), but failed to resolve.

Comment: file_get_contents() return a file contents, it will not execute your PHP file !!!

Comment: @HalayemAnis Then what should I do ??

Comment: seperate the contents : business and presentation .. also STOP USING mysql_* use mysqli_* or PDO instead

Answer (score 1):

dompdf before 0.6.1 would support processing PHP prior to rendering to PDF. That was removed for security reasons and so you should now fully process any PHP in your document prior to feeding it to dompdf.

The code in pdf.php is close, but not quite correct. The following *should* work (I also re-organized for readability).

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");

$tym = date('g:i s');
$filename = 'FAA-8130_3_'.$tym;

ob_start();
require_once 'form.php';
$html = ob_get_clean();
ob_end_clean();

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream($filename. ".pdf", array("Attachment" => 0));
```