# PHP How to instance an inner class

Tags: php, namespaces, nested-class

I have a class called **Pages** used as a namespace, like this:

```
<?php

static class Pages
{
    class Page
    {
        public $Name;
        public $Title;

        public function __construct($Name, $Title)
        {
            $this->Name = $Name;
            $this->Title = $Title;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

**Elsewhere:**

```
<?php

$g_Pages = new Pages::Page("My Name", "My Title");

?>
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting a Parse error: **syntax error, unexpected 'Page' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$'**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error message doesn't appear to relate to the code you have posted.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I was trying to anonymize the example.  The original class names had a different name.  I just edited it to fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to use the inner class as a namespace, just use namespaces.  Ex:

```
<?php
namespace Pages;
class Page { }
```

Then you can access the class through:

```
$g_Pages = new \Pages\Page("My Name", "My Title");
```

http://php.net/namespaces

Comment: Perfect!  Just what I want to do.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately nested classes are not a language feature of PHP.

The below SO page explains this in detail.

[Nested or Inner Class in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424257/nested-or-inner-class-in-php)