# Can we implement interface in PHP class without using implements?

Tags: php, class, interface

I mean can we directly use interface class inside main class as a constructor.

Comment: Really not sure what you're asking here but why don't you simply try it and see if it works?

Comment: Do you mean like [Java's anonymous classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html), ie `$impl = new SomeInterface { /* interface methods here */ };`? PHP 7 has [anonymous classes](http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.anonymous.php). Is that what you're after?

Comment: possible you are talking about [nested or inner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424257/nested-or-inner-class-in-php)

Comment: I mean can we instantiate interface class in PHP as null. TestInterface $test=null;

Comment: Since PHP variables aren't typed, you cannot do that. You can use `$test = null;` though

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't instantiate an Interface in PHP.

```
<?php

interface TestError {
    public function test() {
        print "Bye!"; // Fatal error: Interface function Test::test() cannot contain body
    }
}

interface Test {
    public function test();
}

class Main {
    public function __construct () {
        $test = new Test(); // Fatal error: Cannot instantiate interface
    }
}

$main = new Main();

?>
```