# PHP: method to allow class to be instantiated only in another class

Tags: php

Suppose I have three declared classes:

```
A, B, C
```

Class `A` must be instantiated **only** in class `B`.

Is there a way to specify in itself that class `A` should only be instantiated in class `B` (via constructor for instance) and not in other classes?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110732/how-to-get-name-of-calling-function-method-in-php for how to get the name of the calling function. The constructor can check if the calling function is in one of those classes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424257/nested-or-inner-class-in-php may also be worth a read.