# Create instance of class autoloader

Tags: php, class, model-view-controller, instance

I have class autoloader and if i call `$class = new myClass`, everything is ok, class loaded, instance created.

I want to create instance of class like this `$this->className->myMethod($args)`;`
first create class className and call className's method myMethod?

Is it possible? Can someone post me example, please? Opencart script call modules like this `$this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($category_id)`.

Comment: See the answer by _Antonio Haley_ at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/533459/how-to-do-a-php-nested-class-or-nested-methods

Comment: Oh, thank you very much